# Move UITabBar to the top of a UITabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I just finished designing a application that uses a top bar that toggles between three UIViewControllers. My first thought was to use a UITabBarController, since it works very simular.

However, the tabBar is at the bottom and in my PSD, it's at the top. Is there anyway I can change it? I see in the library I can drag in a UITabBar, but I don't know how to get it to change pages from there.

Please help!
Coulton

Comment: How have you defined your top bar? What is the problem you are facing when you try to move it down?

Comment: It's a bunch of UIButtons. I want to move the UITabBar up to the top. I see the UITabBar in the library, but it's not linked to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it can be done, but you should be aware of [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> "Important: In iPhone OS 3.0 and later, you should not attempt to use the methods and properties of this class to modify the tab bar when it is associated with a tab bar controller object. Modifying the tab bar in this way results in the throwing of an exception. Instead, any modifications to the tab bar or its items should occur through the tab bar controller interface. You may still directly modify a tab bar object that is not associated with a tab bar controller."

So, in your UI (I suppose you defined it in Interface Builder), instantiate a `UITabBar` object (by choosing it in the IB library and dragging it to your view in IB). Choose the default position and also define the way that this tab bar autoresizes (using the size pane of the info window). Then, add an outlet to your view controller of type UITabBar, and, finally, connect the tab bar object to the tab bar outlet.

Once you have done this, in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method you can customize any property of the tab bar that you want to.

Comment: `tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(-100, -100, 320, 60);` does nothing.

Comment: How have you created your tab bar? if I do what I suggested in IB, I can see the tab bar at the top. are you using a tab bar controller?

Comment: I am using a tab bar controller... should it just be a tab bar? If it's just a tab bar, how do I control what view to show on each item? Thanks.

Comment: As the quote I put at the beginning of my answer clearly states, you cannot modify a tab bar when it is associated to a tab bar controller. As to the views it manages, you can set its `items` property. Have a look at the UITabBar reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: I did a little reading up on it, and it just talked about the items. How would you give it a action to change UIViewControllers or UIViews?

Comment: Assign a delegate and define the method: `– tabBar:didSelectItem:`. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate

Answer (score 12):

Hope the below code helps

```
UITabBarController *tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    tabC.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70);

    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:firstObj,secObj, nil];

    tabC.viewControllers = arr;

    [self.window addSubview:tabC.view];
```

Worked fine for me