# UITabBarController with the tab bar at the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a view with three subviews. Like this:

[image]

Then I have a UITabBarController with four tabs, and I want the tab bar to show in the view at the bottom of the first view (the dark grey area). I have this in my viewDidLoad

```
[self.tabBarView addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

That works. Now I want two other things that I'm not managing. First, I want the tabbed view to occupy the entire dark grey area (which is `self.tabBarView`). Also, I want the tabs to show at the top of the window.

[image]

Here the item list is at bottom, but I want them at the top. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move UITabBar to the top of a UITabBarController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633541/move-uitabbar-to-the-top-of-a-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: it's not really a duplicate. I don't just want to move the bar to the top; and using that solution I don't get to use the tab bar controller. Could you please remove the vote?

Comment: From the Apple docs: `Do not modify a tab bar that is managed by a tab bar controller (an instance of the UITabBarController class). If you do so, the system raises an exception.` And it wasn't my down-vote (though I seriously considered giving you one)

Comment: It wasn't a down vote, but the close vote. But why did you consider that?

Comment: There are several other questions asking about moving the tab bar to the top of the screen (most of which strongly recommend against it) and you've shown no clear research effort in attempting any of those solutions to move the tab bar, which appears to be your main question. You could at least _try_ something instead of just saying "I want to do this, show me how."